# Tiny png api post file

Tags: php, image-processing, upload, http-post

I have problem with **tinypng** and with POST file, 
my script is next:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST["mytext"])){
?>          
<form role="form"  action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="images">
 <div class="text-right">   <button type="submit" > send </button></div>
<input type="hidden"  name="mytext" value="submit"/>
</form>     
<?php
}else{
require_once("../../class/upload_opt/Tinify/Exception.php");
require_once("../../class/upload_opt/Tinify/ResultMeta.php");
require_once("../../class/upload_opt/Tinify/Result.php");
require_once("../../class/upload_opt/Tinify/Source.php");
require_once("../../class/upload_opt/Tinify/Client.php");
require_once("../../class/upload_opt/Tinify.php");
\Tinify\setKey("tyzxBs8FRApkkE51q9uao-KlHBnR-9mU");
$name_file=$source = \Tinify\fromFile($_FILES["images"]["name"]);
$source->toFile("optimized.jpg");
echo "ok";
}
?>
```

but when send file with PHP file shows me this error

> Warning: file_get_contents(logo_ckeditor.png): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   D:\itc_project\baft\class\upload_opt\Tinify\Source.php on line 9 Fatal
>   error: Uncaught exception 'Tinify\ClientException' with message 'File
>   is empty (HTTP 400/InputMissing)' in
>   D:\itc_project\baft\class\upload_opt\Tinify\Exception.php:18 Stack
>   trace: #0 D:\itc_project\baft\class\upload_opt\Tinify\Client.php(82):
>   Tinify\Exception::create('File is empty', 'InputMissing', 400) #1
>   D:\itc_project\baft\class\upload_opt\Tinify\Source.php(13):
>   Tinify\Client->request('post', '/shrink', false) #2
>   D:\itc_project\baft\class\upload_opt\Tinify\Source.php(9):
>   Tinify\Source::fromBuffer(false) #3
>   D:\itc_project\baft\class\upload_opt\Tinify.php(65):
>   Tinify\Source::fromFile('logo_ckeditor.p...') #4
>   D:\itc_project\baft\manager\panel\upload_opt.php(28):
>   Tinify\fromFile('logo_ckeditor.p...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   D:\itc_project\baft\class\upload_opt\Tinify\Exception.php on line 18

please help me, how can fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

I see, Issue should be here

```
$name_file=$source = \Tinify\fromFile($_FILES["images"]["name"]);
```

replace it with

```
$name_file=$source = \Tinify\fromFile($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"]);
```